# ¿Como obtengo un "TOP 3" de elementos maximos de un array?

Tags: java, array

Es un ejercicio sobre donaciones, y quieren saber el nombre de cada donador y la cantidad que dona, la suma de todas las donaciones y el top 3 de las mayores donaciones (aquí es donde mi cabeza ha explotado). Sé buscar el maximo valor de un array, pero no llego a comprender como encontrar el top 2 y 3. Os dejo el codigo que he hecho hasta el momento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo del TOP ya se que me da mal pero era por poner algo, todo me funciona perfecto menos el TOP que no tengo ni idea. Un saludo y Gracias a todos. PD: Está en el main y es lenguaje de java.

Comment: En StackOverflow es una buena practica incluir el codigo original en vez de capturas de pantalla :)

Comment: Una propuesta: Y si en vez de recorrer el arreglo buscando el/los TOP, ordenas el arreglo y tomas los primeros 3?

Comment: Aunque en programación todo se puede resolver de diferentes formas, la más común es crear una clase Donador con las dos propiedades (nombre y cantidad donada). Luego en esa clase implementas la interface `Comparable` y su respectivo método `compareTo` para que puedas ordenar posteriormente el arreglo de Donadores según la cantidad donada y el top 3 quedaría en las primeras 3 posiciones del array o en las últimas 3 según la implementación del método `compareTo` después de haberlo ordenado.